# Newsletter subscribe confirmation plugin [Magento 2]

Tags: magento2, newsletter, plugin, magento2.2-dev

I'm writing a small plugin that intercepts the `Subscriber` class (`Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber`), fetches the subscriber email address/id and pushes it further to our api.

This works well when the 'Need to Confirm' option is set to 'No'. However, when I enable the double opt-in and the confirmation email is sent and clicked, Magento completely ignores the 'SubscriberPlugin' file, even though it still actually uses the main, original class 'Subscriber' (proved by placing error_log(**FILE**) in the original class file).

I know that when a user clicks the confirmation link, the method triggered in the `Subscriber` class is `confirm`. With that knowledge I've added a new method `afterConfirm` to the `SubscriberPlugin` file, but that for now will do nothing, as like mentioned above, Magento is ignoring the plugin file when a user confirms subscription.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it working. All I needed to do was to remove the contents of the /generated/ folder.